# Opensource Android webview supported javascript chart and graph plugins

Tags: gratis, android, javascript, graphs, charts

I am looking for an open source Android JavaScript based chart plugins.

I found mostly commercial plugins like HighChart and Zoom Charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Chart for JS](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/mobile/#chart|areachart) supports Mobile platforms and is compatible with Android WebView. The whole product suite is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program.

There is also a native [Android Chart](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/android/Chart) included in the package.

-Davis(Syncfusion)

Answer (score 1):

[LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/) works in Android, IOS and all operating systems with WebView or equivalent host control. It's free for personal use.